# Get (x,y) of point after rotation in image (python,openCV)

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the coordination of point after rotating with rotation matrix in OpenCV? Is there anyway to find it by multiply point in rotating matrix?
(The point which is confusing is that in openCV rotation matrix is 2*3 not 2*2 so I'm a little confused about that)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The formula defining the relationship between source and destination coordinates is in [the documentation of `warpAffine`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if have got the question right. You have a point (x,y) which is subjected to rotation. You want to find the new (x,y).

To do this , you can easily use perspective transform available in openCV.
The cv2.perspectiveTransform() function accepts a numpy array with your original points and another numpy array with your transformation matrix and return a numpy array with the transformed points.

Check this link for details regarding the function .[Perspective Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=perspectivetransform#perspectivetransform).

Your transformation matrix should be 3x3 matrix in this case.

a1 a2 a3
a4 a5 a6            > Take this as your transformation matrix
a7 a8 a9

a1,a2,a4,a5 will be your rotation matrix in this case.
set a3,a6,a7,a8 to 0
Set a9 to 1

This should do it.